# mootools fx working except in ie9

Tags: mootools

This is my first attempt with Mootools, so I welcome a critique of the code.

I have a dynamic list of images that expand on the 'click" event and contract on the 'mouseout' event. The code works fine in all browsers (FF, Safari, Chrome, even the smartphones) but not in IE9 (JS is enabled)

Anyone with similar problem or solution?

I plan to use a lightbox effect, downloading a larger & clearer image to the center of the page, instead of just resizing a small image. However, I am hesitant to attempt this, if there is problems with IE9.

I have coded three image sizes with the upload commit, so the larger image is available for the lightbox, but, I don't see anything in mootools for a lightbox, or am I missing it?

```
$i = 0;
while($i < count($validate)) {
    <div class="validate">
        <div class="validate_image_<?php echo $validate[$i]['validate_type']; ?>">
            <div class="validate_image" id="validate_image_wrapper_<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <?php 
                if ($validate[$i]['validate_image_filename'] != '') {
                    if (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . 'validate_image/' . str_replace('.', '_medium.', $validate[$i]['validate_image_filename']))) {
                        echo '<img src="' . UPLOAD_URL . 'validate_image/' . str_replace('.', '_medium.', $validate[$i]['validate_image_filename']) . '" alt="Listing Image" />';
                } else {

                        echo '<img src="' . UPLOAD_URL . 'validate_image/' . str_replace('.', '_large.', $validate[$i]['validate_image_filename']) .  '" alt="Listing image"  />';
                }

            } else {
               ?>   
               <img src="/images/no_image_posted_validate.png" alt="no image posted"  />
               <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>

  ... remainder of HTML display code 


function setupEnlargeImage() {
    window.myFx = new Fx({
            duration: 200,
            transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeOut
    });

    $$('.validate_image').addEvent('click', function() {
         window.selectedImage = this.id;
         myFx.start(1,2.0);
    });

    $$('.validate_image').addEvent('mouseout', function() {
        window.selectedImage = this.id;
        myFx.start(1.0,1);
    });

    myFx.set = function(value) {
        var style = "scale(" + (value) + ")";
        $(window.selectedImage).setStyles({
            "-webkit-transform": style,
            "-moz-transform": style,
            "-o-transform": style,
            "-ms-transform": style,
            transform: style
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Open up the console... do you see any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Well, no solution for IE9, however I went to Slimbox for the images and it works fine in IE9.

So, this question is closed.